# Cannot submit new contributions through webpage - One of the parameters (value:) is not of type integer

Tags: civicontribute

We're seeing the error 'One of the parameters (value:) is not of type integer' when submitting a new donation through a contribution page on CiviCRM 5.4.1. All custom templates have been removed so it should only be using the core Civi files. Here's the backtrace. Has anyone seen this or have any thoughts on the cause or resolution?

backTrace

```
0 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(377): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()

1 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(554): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer")

2 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1500): CRM_Utils_Type::validate("", "Integer")

3 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1464): CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM civicrm_membership WHERE contact_id = %1 AND me...", (Array:1), TRUE)

4 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesConditions/Membership/ContactHasMembership.php(57): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM civicrm_membership WHERE contact_id = %1 AND me...", (Array:1))

5 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/Engine.php(279): CRM_CivirulesConditions_Membership_ContactHasMembership->isConditionValid(Object(CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_Post))

6 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/Engine.php(241): CRM_Civirules_Engine::checkCondition((Array:5), Object(CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_Post))

7 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/Engine.php(27): CRM_Civirules_Engine::areConditionsValid(Object(CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_Post))

8 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/Trigger/Post.php(90): CRM_Civirules_Engine::triggerRule(Object(CRM_Civirules_Trigger_Post), Object(CRM_Civirules_TriggerData_Post))

9 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/Civirules/Trigger/Post.php(75): CRM_Civirules_Trigger_Post->triggerTrigger("create", "MembershipPayment", "15556", Object(CRM_Member_DAO_MembershipPayment))

10 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/civirules.php(225): CRM_Civirules_Trigger_Post::post("create", "MembershipPayment", "15556", Object(CRM_Member_DAO_MembershipPayment))

11 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(282): civirules_civicrm_post("create", "MembershipPayment", "15556", Object(CRM_Member_DAO_MembershipPayment))

12 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/WordPress.php(155): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:5), "civicrm_post", 4, "create", "MembershipPayment", "15556", Object(CRM_Member_DAO_MembershipPayment), NULL, NULL)

13 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(98): CRM_Utils_Hook_WordPress->invokeViaUF(4, "create", "MembershipPayment", "15556", Object(CRM_Member_DAO_MembershipPayment), NULL, NULL, "civicrm_post")

14 [internal function](): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent), "hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))

15 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(164): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent), "hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher))

16 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(53): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:2), "hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))

17 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php(167): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))

18 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(47): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))

19 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(366): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_post", Object(Civi\Core\Event\PostEvent))

20 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/MembershipPayment.php(71): CRM_Utils_Hook::post("create", "MembershipPayment", "15556", Object(CRM_Member_DAO_MembershipPayment))

21 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php(1825): CRM_Member_BAO_MembershipPayment::create((Array:3))

22 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(1592): CRM_Member_BAO_Membership::linkMembershipPayment(Object(CRM_Member_BAO_Membership), Object(CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution))

23 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(1405): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->postProcessMembership((Array:71), "12546", Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), (Array:49), (Array:0), (Array:3), (Array:13), (Array:1), TRUE, NULL, FALSE, "2", (Array:1), TRUE)

24 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(2426): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processMembership((Array:60), "12546", (Array:0), (Array:3), (Array:49), (Array:1))

25 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(2301): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->doMembershipProcessing("12546", (Array:60), (Array:49), (Array:1))

26 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(722): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processFormSubmission("12546")

27 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(489): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->postProcess()

28 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()

29 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next", "Next")

30 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next")

31 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next")

32 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")

33 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)

34 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): 
CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))

35 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52):         CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))

36 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1246): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))

37 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(141): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()

38 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))

39 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))

40 /var/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(515): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))

41 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp.php(726): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))

42 /var/www/wp-includes/functions.php(960): WP->main("")

43 /var/www/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()

44 /var/www/index.php(17): require("/var/www/wp-blog-header.php")

45 {main}
```

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
>   One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer

Comment: Is there any backtrace info missing from the question?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, the full 45 items and error message are all that showed up when trying to submit a web donation.

Comment: ok - I see it is added now. Done some formatting on the question so that it is readable.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the formatting assist, I'll try to get it right next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the backtrace, it looks like the error pops up from the `civirules` extension enabled on your site. Make sure you have updated it to the latest version available at https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules

Comment: If that doesnt work try disabling some specific rules and find out which rule is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that was it, I should have thought to check the rules extension sooner. Looks like they're not planning to extend functionality beyond 5.1, so we'll just need to uninstall and find another way to set up some automation. Answer accepted.